# Assigned return values from multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having an issue as I'm trying to develop a candlestick interpreter. Software iterates lines which is currencies and inside each it starts processes to check for certain candlestick pattern on different timeframe.

points is a dictionary with key being timeframe in string format and value being points for how high it ranks, that information is also rendered to the file at the end.

The problem I'm having is that it appears as "bdd" is always empty so no values are ever written into the points dictionary.

```
import talib
import yfinance as yf
import operator
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 
def Fetch(bdd, timeframe, line, y1d, y1wk, points):
    if(timeframe == "15m"):
        data_15m = yf.download(line, start=df(y1d), interval="15m", threads=1)
        if data_15m.empty is False:
            points["15m"] = GetMarketPoints(data_15m, line)
            bdd["15m"] = (points["15m"], data_15m)
            #queue.put((points["15m"], data_15m))
            #return (points["15m"], data_15m)

    elif(timeframe == "30m"):
        data_30m = yf.download(line, start=df(y1d), interval="30m", threads=1)
        if data_30m.empty is False:
            points["30m"] = GetMarketPoints(data_30m, line)
            bdd["30m"] = (points["30m"], data_30m)
            #queue.put((points["30m"], data_30m))
            #return (points["30m"], data_30m)     

    elif(timeframe == "1h"):
        data_1h = yf.download(line, start=df(y1d), interval="1h", threads=1)
        if data_1h.empty is False:
            points["1h"] = GetMarketPoints(data_1h, line)
            bdd["1h"] = (points["1h"], data_1h)
            #queue.put((points["1h"], data_1h))
            #return (points["1h"], data_1h)

    elif(timeframe == "1d"):
        data_1d = yf.download(line, start=df(y1d), interval="1d", threads=1)
        if data_1d.empty is False:
            points["1d"] = GetMarketPoints(data_1d, line)
            bdd["1d"] = (points["1d"], data_1d)
            #queue.put((points["1d"], data_1d))
            #return (points["1d"], data_1d)

    else:
        data_1wk = yf.download(line, start=df(y1wk), interval="1wk", threads=1)
        if data_1wk.empty is False:
            points["1wk"] = GetMarketPoints(data_1wk, line)
            bdd["1wk"] = (points["1wk"], data_1wk)
            #queue.put((points["1wk"], data_1wk))
            #return (points["1wk"], data_1wk)

#Dateformat
def df(date):
    return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def GetMarketPoints(data, line):
    point = 0

    MorningDojiStar = talib.CDLMORNINGDOJISTAR(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Morning Doji Star'] = MorningDojiStar
    morningdojistar_days = data[data['Morning Doji Star'] > 0]
    if (morningdojistar_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Morning Doji Star")
    if data[data['Morning Doji Star'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    Harami = talib.CDLHARAMI(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Harami'] = Harami
    harami_days = data[data['Harami'] > 0]
    if (harami_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Harami")
    if data[data['Harami'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    Piercing = talib.CDLPIERCING(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Piercing'] = Piercing
    piercing_days = data[data['Piercing'] > 0]
    if (piercing_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Piercing")
    if data[data['Piercing'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    MorningStar = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Morning Star'] = MorningStar
    morningstar_days = data[data['Morning Star'] > 0]
    if (morningstar_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Morning Star")
    if data[data['Morning Star'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    Engulfing = talib.CDLENGULFING(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Engulfing'] = Engulfing
    engulfing_days = data[data['Engulfing'] > 0]
    if (engulfing_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Engulfing")
    if data[data['Engulfing'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    Hammer = talib.CDLHAMMER(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], data['Close'])
    data['Hammer'] = Hammer
    hammer_days = data[data['Hammer'] > 0]
    if (hammer_days.empty is False):
        point += 1
        print(line + " Hammer")
    if data[data['Hammer'] < 0].empty is False:
        print("Negative pattern. Ignores Points")
        point -= 1

    return point

def TheBigFunction():
    #Point Weights
    pointweights = {
        "15m": 0.25,
        "30m": 0.5,
        "1h": 1,
        "1d": 24,
        "1wk": 168
    }

    bdd = {}
    queue = Queue()

    f = open("crypto.txt","r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    to_buy = {}
    THRESHOLD = 2
    presentday = datetime.now() # or presentday = datetime.today()
    jobs = []

    y1d = presentday - timedelta(days=1)
    y1wk = presentday - timedelta(days=7)

    # Write File
    day = '{:%d-%m-%Y}'.format(datetime.today())

    for line in lines:
        
        print(line + "\n")
        #Initialize to Zero
        totalPoints = 0
        points = {
            "15m": 0,
            "30m": 0,
            "1h": 0,
            "1d": 0,
            "1wk": 0
        }
        timeframes = ["15m", "30m", "1h", "1d", "1wk"]
        dataframes = {}

        for key in points.keys():
            print("q2" + str(queue))
        
            print("bdd" +  str(bdd))
            proc = Process(target=Fetch, args=(bdd, key, line, y1d, y1wk, points))
            jobs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()    

        print("q2" + str(queue))
        
        print(bdd.values())

        for i, returnValue in enumerate(bdd):
            points[timeframes[i]], dataframes[timeframes[i]] = returnValue
            totalPoints += points[timeframes[i]] * pointweights[timeframes[i]]

        if totalPoints > THRESHOLD:
            filename = str(day) +".txt"
            f = open(filename, "a+")
            f.write("TICKER: " + line + " Points: " + str(totalPoints) + "\n")
            f.write("15M: " + str(points["15m"]) + "\n")
            f.write("30M: " + str(points["30m"]) + "\n")
            f.write("1H: " + str(points["1h"]) + "\n")
            f.write("1D: " + str(points["1d"]) + "\n")
            f.write("1wk: " + str(points["1wk"]) + "\n")
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()

    print(f);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheBigFunction()
```

Comment: processes don't share variables. It doesn't send to process reference to `bcc` but it sends only values from `bcc` using `pickle`. You have to use queue to send result back to main process and put in `bcc` . But it needs to send `queue` to process as argument.

Comment: if you would use `Pool` then you could run `results = pool.map(func, list_of_data)`

Answer (score 0):

Processes don't share variables. `Process()` doesn't send `bcc` as reference but only as values (using file `pickle`). So every process has own `bcc` and if you set value in `bcc` in `Fetch` then it can't change `bcc` in main process. You have to use `queue` to send result back to main process. And it needs to send `queue` to `Fetch`.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def fetch(value, queue):  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions
    queue.put( (value, "some data") )

# --- main ---

points = {
            "15m": 0,
            "30m": 0,
            "1h": 0,
            "1d": 0,
            "1wk": 0
        }

q = Queue()
jobs = []

for key in points.keys():

    # send `queue` to `fetch`
    proc = Process(target=fetch, args=(key, q))

    jobs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()    

# get all results from processes
while not q.empty():    
    result = q.get()
    print(result)
```

---

**BTW:**

`jobs = []` should be inside `for line`-loop but you have it ouside `for line`-loop

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution posed by @furas:

You could pass a *managed* dictionary instead of a regular dictionary:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager
...

def TheBigFunction():
    ...
    manager = Manager()
    bdd = manager.dict() # a managed dictionary
    ... # etc.
```

Variable `bdd` is now a proxy object. A method call on `bdd` results in more-or-less the equivalent of a remote method call to a server process started when the `manager.Manager()` statement was executed. The underlying communication mechanism is either a socket (Linux) or named pipe (Windows). So performance is clearly not going to be the same as when dealing with regular dictionaries, which, however, cannot work in your situation.